# Cocos2D - Change color of a sprite to what it was

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am changing the color of my sprite using the following code

```
 sprite.color = ccc3(255, 0, 0);
```

it changes the color to red..

How can I change the color to what it was??

Thanks..

Comment: Would it be possible to save the original color?

    originalColor = sprite.color;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return to original color by using

> sprite.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);

the original color was not lost. the tint methods (ccc3 in this case) are not adding-color, but darkening the individual RGB channels. That's the reason you cant tint a black image to any other color.

In your example, you didn't paint your sprite Red. You've just cut all channels except the  red one

Comment: I was looking for some documentation on exactly what setColor meant on a sprite, but this answer helps a lot!